# WordPress plugin activation error: unexpected output during activation

Tags: php, wordpress

The plugin generated 880 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

i get this error when i install my plugin , please anyone can help 
here is the code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post Bottom Content Generator
Plugin URI: NULL
Description: This will add a image with url at the end of the post content.
Version:  1.0
Author: All Marketing Solutions
Author URI: 
*/
//table creation in the wordpress database
global $AMS_post_plugin_db_version;
$AMS_post_plugin_db_version = "1.0";
function create_AMS_table () 
{
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "AMS_post_plugin";
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      AMS_post_plugin_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      AMS_post_plugin_time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      AMS_post_plugin_name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
      AMS_post_plugin_url VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
      AMS_post_plugin_path VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    add_option("AMS_post_plugin_db_version", $AMS_post_plugin_db_version);
}
function insert_AMS_table() 
{
   global $wpdb;
   $name = "talha";
   $url = "talha";
   $path="talha";
   $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'AMS_post_plugin_time' => current_time('mysql'), 'AMS_post_plugin_name' => $name, 'AMS_post_plugin_url' => $url, 'AMS_post_plugin_path' => $path ) );
}
///these will activate these functions when plugin install
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'create_AMS_table');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'insert_AMS_table');
?>
```

Comment: problem solved , just eidt this line

Comment: AMS_post_plugin_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, to AMS_post_plugin_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,

Comment: remove the auto_increment , and your code will work